# how can I call back to previous application problematically in ios swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have made a custom keyboard in which in which i made a call of `openURL()`,
so that I can open the containing application to capture `text` through `OCR`. Then i have made a `userdefault` for the application group and stored the text into it, so that the keyboard extension can read it.

But the problem here is just that when the containing app completes `OCR` and store the text, after that i want it to go back to previous application automatically rather then tapping on the top left button of `Go-to-previous-app`.

Comment: Searching for same answer. Could you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You may open URL in UIWebView In new Controller after completion pop View Controller. I think it helps you.